# vb.net e.Graphics.MeasureString() Assistance Needed

Tags: vb.net, string, events, size

So I'm getting ready to call a Function that will draw the contents of a `RichTextBox` using `e.Graphics.DrawString()`, that part works fine. However, I don't want the string to be drawn if it is past a certain length. I have the string stored in `Master_Longest_String`.

One way I figured out was using `e.Graphics.MeasureString()`. You pass it the string and the font it is in and it gives me the length. I then compare the length to some other variables and figure out if I want to draw it or not.

My problem is, Im not sure how to call the `MeasureStr` function?

I made this:

```
Private Sub Results()
  Msgbox(MeasureStr())
End Sub

Private Function MeasureStr(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) As SizeF
    Dim stringSize As New SizeF
    stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(Master_Longest_String, Print_Font).width
    Return stringsize
End Function
```

However, when my sub calls `MeasureStr()`, it wants an argument `(e)`, but I'm not sure what to pass to it?

Comment: Turn Option Strict On...

Comment: You need to pass the text and font to your method. Then use the `Graphics.MeasureString` and pass your text and font to it to get the length...

Comment: I am, 3rd to last line: (Master_Longest_String, Print_Font)

Comment: I know what it means you are using it wrong. Want a quick fix you need to pass in paint events. But from what is the question. You don't need paint events to use the function to do this...

Comment: Yes that was one of my problems, But i think I was trying to call an event handler directly, which isn't a very good idea.

Comment: Did you see my post? It will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim sI As SizeF 
 Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)
  sI = g.MeasureString("yourtexthere", yourfonthere)
 End Using

 Return sI
```

Put that in your function and remove the paint arguments from method... Now you don't have to worry about the paint argument or any control to get the length...